# Will having a lot of classes to process each command separately lag my pc?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Is having many classes for each command and process them a non-efficient way to run, or is it negligible and I can just leave it to do the way it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a command management method, or something like JDAUtils, it shouldn't make it much slower, but generally if you start you classes something like this

```
if (event.getAuthor().isBot())return;
String prefix = //some reference;
String exact = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
String lower = exact.toLowerCase();
String[] arguments = message.split(" ");
```

and check for processes this demands resources when you run a lot of classes
If you don't have a separate class for every command this shouldn't matter.
AFAIK try JDA Utils it makes managing simpler